# Integrate Swagger with Dropwizard, not able to produce the swagger.json file

Tags: java, rest, maven-3, swagger, dropwizard

I have done the following steps:

I have a existing drop-wizard project setup [0.8 version].

Added dependence

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.12</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.1-M2</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have added the @Api annotations to my resource file.

I have added the following code to the application run class:

```
environment.jersey().register(new ApiListingResource());
BeanConfig config = new BeanConfig();
        config.setTitle("default Application");
        config.setVersion("1.0.0");
        config.setResourcePackage("com.class.where.the.api.annotation.are");
        config.setScan(true);
```

The problem is when I run the application I can't get the swagger.json by going to http://localhost:8080/swagger.json.

pretty much follow the example here: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/tree/master/samples/java-dropwizard

Does anyone know what the problem is? What else do I need to setup? [The application runs and start up fine, I just can't get to that swagger.json file]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using conflicting and incomplete dependencies. If you take a look at the https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-samples/tree/master/java/java-dropwizard sample, you'll see that you actually need to include:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
  <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.1-M1</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
      <artifactId>*</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

and only that (no swagger-core directly). If you do follow that with a similar configuration to what you have, it should work fine.

Comment: Looks like I have some dependency issues using swagger-jersey-jaxrs. Dropwizard 0.8 uses Jersey version 2.x+ and swagger-jersey-jaxrs is using Jersey version 1.x.x. It seems like jersey 2.x+ is only supported by swagger-jersey2-jaxrs_2.10. So how do I need to setup swagger-jersey2-jaxrs_2.10 in such way that swagger would work?

Comment: I've updated the dependency in the answer, try that.

Comment: I got it to work by using the following dependency <dependency>
    <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
    <artifactId>swagger-jersey2-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1-M2</version>
   </dependency>

Comment: Looks like 1.5.1-M2 is having some jetty and jersey dependency errors.

Comment: ! java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.util.collection.Values.lazy(Lorg/glassfish/jersey/internal/util/collection/Value;)Lorg/glassfish/jersey/internal/util/collection/Value;
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346) ~[jersey-container-servlet-core-2.1.ja

Comment: Hi Ron, first of all thank you for your help. Do you know if there is a way to integrate the api-doc with this? for example if I go to localhost:8080/apidoc it will show a GUI doc version of the rest api rather than the json or yaml representation at localhost:8080/swagger.json.  Right now my config bean looks like this --------BeanConfig config = new BeanConfig();
        config.setTitle("default Application");
        config.setVersion("1.0.0");
        config.setResourcePackage("com.class.where.the.api.annotation.are");
        config.setScan(true);

Comment: Take a look at the samples we have to see how we integrate the UI in them. There's a maven process that downloads and deploys it as part of the build process.

Comment: Hi Ron, can you refer me to the link? Also it so possible to host the doc file on the same url as dropwizard app?

Comment: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/blob/master/samples/java-dropwizard/pom.xml#L63-L105 You may be able to host them at the same URL, responding to different content-type requests but this is out of scope for the question and entirely not worth the trouble.

Comment: so it looks like this copies the swagger ui distribution into the build jar without the index.html. I need to construct my own index.html with the embedded swagger.json url that references my resources correct?

Comment: You need to make your own copy if the index.html with the correct url, yes.